# How to obtain UBUNTU IOS?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I wanna install Linux to my  Desktop. How can I get UBUNTU IOS hope this helps - [Projects in Linux](https://www.udemy.com/projects-in-linux-learn-linux-doing-real-world-projects/?couponCode=UJLINUX18)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please specify where you face the problems during installation.

Comment: CD-ROM drives do not support reading from discs that were burned at high speeds using a modern CD writer.

Comment: As well as CD-ROM fails to boot

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full installation for ubuntu instruction from the below article link. 
http://joms3.com/articles/data/making_bootable_disk_of_operating_system.php

Hope this will help full for you

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing dear !!

Comment: Can I get started here with LINUX - https://www.udemy.com/projects-in-linux-learn-linux-doing-real-world-projects/?couponCode=UJLINUX18